# Search form submit by enter and image button?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, wordpress

I'm customizing Wordpress's Twenty Eleven 'SearchForm' / 'searchform.php' --

I want to keep the Enter-to-Search functionality; but I want to add my custom Image button for users to also have the traditional click-button-submit.

***HOWEVER;*** when I drag the Ids, classes, and name used on the functional default to the new Image button - my image does not display. But, when I don't have those classes, etc used.. It renders?

Below is where I'm currently at with the code. (Any suggestions?)

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying search forms in Twenty Eleven
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Eleven
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 */
?>

<form method="get" id="searchform" name="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
<label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></label>
<input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" value="Search, title, author, keyword" onfocus="ClearForm();" style="width: 225px;">
<input type="submit" src="http://#/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/searchnav_btn.gif" style="position:absolute;" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search' ); ?>" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit"/>

<input type="image" src="#/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/searchnav_btn.gif" style="position:absolute;" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search' ); ?>" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit"/>

</form>

<script language="javascript">
<!--
function ClearForm() {
  document.searchform.submit.value= "";
}

//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Likely there is css attached to the id and classes set on the submit button.  An id is supposed to be unique and therefore only one element on the page should have a particular id.  Without knowing the styles that are being applied to the id and class it is hard to say where your image is being placed.  Though since they are both absolutely positioned it is possible your image is behind the other one.

Comment: Word of advise: use a child theme http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes You only override the files you need to override

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding a z-index to the image styling to see if it will appear on top.

Comment: But, I guess that's the best I got. Accepted.